# Hiding Action list Agents from users

Tags: action, lotus

Lotus Notes : 
We have a support Department that use the support agents in the actions Agent list, and they also have access to use Other Agents with editors access.

The problem is the users/clients have the same access as support and can also see and make use of these agents, which we don't want to allow. I had a look at the agents security options, and know that you can set the access to an admin group or person within the access control.

What I am not sure about is by not allowing the users to have access to these agents, and some features on the forms or views calls one od the agents, would it prevent the functionality from working ? and if so, does any one know about a work around ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the agents on the Actions menu.  I.e., set them to "Agent list selection" instead of "Action menu selection".

Then create a mechanism that can launch the agents but can only be seen by the admin group.  For example, create View Actions that use `@Command([RunAgent];"agent nanme");` and set up a hide-when formula in the properties for the Actions - something like `(!@UserRole = "[Admin]")`. If you don't like that option, you could create a Page that is hidden from regular users, and turn that page into a menu for the admins, using hotspots or buttons to trigger the agents.